# When I try to traverse a cursor received from a procedure, I get an error in the cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Good afternoon mates,

I have a procedure performed in Oracle, which has a parameter that is cursor type and is output.

I have the variable declared, and the procedure returns data to me in the other output parameters

```
   procedure SP_SOLANTECEDLICE   (
     P_FECHA  NUMBER,
     P_ISAPRE VARCHAR2   ) is

     fecha      number(10);
     c_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
     ERR_CODIGO NUMBER(10);
     ERR_GLOSA  VARCHAR2(1000);

     --  r c_cursor%ROWTYPE;
      begin

     PKG_SRENTA.SP_getCARTAS(P_FECHA,
                                          P_ISAPRE,
                                          2,
                                          ERR_CODIGO,
                                          ERR_GLOSA,
                                          c_cursor);
     dbms_output.put_line(ERR_CODIGO);
     if (ERR_CODIGO = 0)
     then


       for c in c_cursor loop
         dbms_output.put_line('ciclo');
       end loop;
     end if;
      end SP_SOLANTECEDLICE;
```

When I execute the code I get the following error:
C_CURSOR IS NOT PROCEDURE OR IS UNDEFINED

HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS PROBLEM?
PLEASE HELP

Comment: Does SP_SOLANTECEDLICE raise that error, or PKG_SRENTA.SP_getCARTAS?

Comment: It appears that the error must be coming from `PKG_SRENTA.SP_getCARTAS` because the only place you print an error is after calling that procedure. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the code for `PKG_SRENTA.SP_getCARTAS` in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because `sys_refcursor` cannot be used as `for c in c_cursor loop`( `c_cursor` as being `sys_refcursor` ), try to use with `fetch ..into`  clause such as :

```
create or replace procedure SP_SOLANTECEDLICE(P_FECHA  NUMBER,
                                              P_ISAPRE VARCHAR2) is

  fecha      number(10);
  c_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  ERR_CODIGO NUMBER(10);
  ERR_GLOSA  VARCHAR2(1000);

begin

  PKG_SRENTA.SP_getCARTAS(P_FECHA,P_ISAPRE,2,ERR_CODIGO,ERR_GLOSA,c_cursor);
  dbms_output.put_line(ERR_CODIGO);
  if (ERR_CODIGO = 0) then
    loop
      fetch c_cursor
        into fecha;
      exit when c_cursor%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(fecha);
    end loop;
  end if;

end SP_SOLANTECEDLICE;
```

where `sys_refcursor` is a buffer space to allocate a value for a `numeric`, `string` column or `rowtype` variable, and for this reason returning into fecha been used as an example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I made the changes you indicated. the code stayed like this:

Now, when it goes through the following line of code: 

 fetch c_cursor

it gives me the following error:
ORA-06504: the return types of result set variables or the query do not match

Comment: it may stem from `PKG_SRENTA.SP_getCARTAS` which has `c_cursor` as the last argument. How is it defined within that procedure ?